# How can i load an API call for this weather API to display inside a div in my html page

Tags: html, jquery, api

I have this weather API plugin and my api key and i would like to show the data it displays inside a div. RIght now if i enter this link into my browser it shows me the correct weather info. My question is how do i get this data to display in a div in my web page.

API call (link): http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Montreal&mode=html&appid=4a5344b7f84ba5c5c620525315413734

If you enter this link above in any browser it will work.

I haven't tried anything because its just a link, so obviously adding it anywhere on my page doesn't make sense. I think this has something to do with a GET request perhaps...?

Comment: This appears to load HTML. So you could simply use `.load()`. Please review: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example from your post.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".weatherbug > div:eq(1)").load("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Montreal&mode=html&appid=4a5344b7f84ba5c5c620525315413734");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="weatherbug">
  <div>My Weather</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol ok rookie moment. That was so obvious i didn't even think to try it lol. thanks buddy!

Comment: @UrielBitton dig into their docs, it may need you to Post the API Key or something like that. In  that case, `load()` may not be helpful.

Comment: i have their docs, can you take a quick look and tell me if i do indeed need a POST request for the key?

https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: @UrielBitton appears to be passive, so GET is fine: https://openweathermap.org/appid#use

Comment: @UrielBitton if this helped, feel free to Upvote it. If this is the answer, mark it.